How to disable group head when using expand=true
Expand=true is setting group head by default. how to disable group head?
Am trying expand=true in my query to group the results, my query looks like fq={!collapse field=your_field}&expand=true. Am getting group heads of each group in the response by default.
How to disable group head so I get all the results in expanded section.

As per expand and collapse the group head by default will come in response, we need to iterate the "response" section and then get the "expanded" for each group..
Refer the below document
https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/collapse-and-expand-results.html
"Inside the expanded section there is a map with each group head pointing to the expanded documents that are within the group. As applications iterate the main collapsed result set, they can access the expanded map to retrieve the expanded groups."
